# menuitem - switch doesn't show up on ActionBar

Tags: java, android, xml

I'd like to place a switch on the actionbar of my main menu. The empty space is there i can click on it, but there is no switch. What can be the solution?

Thanks in advance!

switch_layout.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/switchView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

<android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat
    android:id="@+id/switchForActionBar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text=""/>
```

activtiy_main_action.xml:

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/myswitch"
    android:title=""
    app:showAsAction="always"
    android:actionLayout="@layout/switch_layout">
</item>
```

MainActivity.java

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater menuinf = getMenuInflater();
    menuinf.inflate(R.menu.activity_main_action, menu);
    //getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.mainmenu, menu);

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change this in your menu

**use** `app:actionLayout="@layout/switch_layout"`

**insted of**
`android:actionLayout="@layout/switch_layout"`

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/myswitch"
    android:title=""
    app:showAsAction="always"
    app:actionLayout="@layout/switch_layout">
</item>
```

**and for access your switch use below code**

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.badge_menu, menu);
    MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.myswitch);
    MenuItemCompat.setActionView(item, R.layout.switch_layout);
    RelativeLayout notifCount = (RelativeLayout) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(item)

    Switch switch_button = (Switch) notifCount.findViewById(R.id.switchForActionBar);

    switch_button.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            // do something, the isChecked will be
            // true if the switch is in the On position
        }
    });
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Comment: The switch appeared! Thanks very mutch for your quick help

Comment: *i'm trying but for some reason I have to wait* DONE

Comment: Instead of     Switch switch_button = (Switch) notifCount.findViewById(R.id.switchForActionBar); use 
        SwitchCompat switchCompat = (SwitchCompat) notifCount.findViewById(R.id.switchForActionBar); This is fine now.